# Static async function in JavaScript class

Tags: javascript, class, async-await, javascript-objects

I'm having trouble with a static async method on a JavaScript class.
If I remove the static keyword it works fine to call within the class but then I won't be able to call it by using the class.

My desired outcome is to use the exist method on the class itself using `User.exist(email)` and on an instance of the class, e.g. `foo.exist(email)`.

Where do I think wrong?

```
const userEmails = []

class User {
  constructor(fields) {
   this.email = fields.email;
   this.name = fields.name;
  }

  static async exist(email) {
    return setTimeout(function() {
      return userEmails.includes(email)
    }, 2000)
  }

  async storeEmail() {
    let userExist = await this.exist(this.email)

    if (userExist) {
      console.log('User exist')
    } else {
      users.push(this.email)
      console.log(userEmails)
    }
  }
};

let foo = new User({email: 'foo@bar.com', name: 'Foo Bar'})

foo.storeEmail()           // this.exist is not a function
User.exist('foo@bar.com')  // Works when used inside async function with await
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you define the method of a class as static member, it is not available on instance using `this` keyword. You can directly call it using the class name inside class functions like `User.exist(this.email)`

```js
const userEmails = []

class User {
  constructor(fields) {
   this.email = fields.email;
   this.name = fields.name;
  }

  static async exist(email) {
    return setTimeout(function() {
      return userEmails.includes(email)
    }, 2000)
  }

  async storeEmail() {
    let userExist = await User.exist(this.email)

    if (userExist) {
      console.log('User exist')
    } else {
      users.push(this.email)
      console.log(userEmails)
    }
  }
};

let foo = new User({email: 'foo@bar.com', name: 'Foo Bar'})

foo.storeEmail()           // this.exist is not a function
User.exist('foo@bar.com')  // Works when used inside async function with
```

Comment: Well that was easy... :) Thanks!

Comment: Glad to have helped :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to call your static function in a static context, so `User.exist()` instead of `this.exist()`:

```js
const userEmails = []

class User {
  constructor(fields) {
   this.email = fields.email;
   this.name = fields.name;
  }

  static async exist(email) {
    return setTimeout(function() {
      return userEmails.includes(email)
    }, 2000)
  }

  async storeEmail() {
    let userExist = await User.exist(this.email)

    if (userExist) {
      console.log('User exist')
    } else {
      users.push(this.email)
      console.log(userEmails)
    }
  }
};

let foo = new User({email: 'foo@bar.com', name: 'Foo Bar'})

foo.storeEmail();          // OK
User.exist('foo@bar.com'); // OK
```

Comment: Thank you for your time!
Shubham was a bit quicker and wil recive the answer.